# sed multiple arguments in bash

Tags: sed

I am trying to extract some part of each line from a big txt file with a lot of lines.

I paste here three different cases that I can find in my txt file:

```
>HL282366.10.1371 Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Peptostreptococcales-Tissierellales;Anaerovoracaceae;[Eubacterium] nodatum group;unidentified

>Bacteria;Proteobacteria;Gammaproteobacteria;Pseudomonadales;Pseudomonadaceae;Pseudomonas;amygdali;

>Archaea;Proteobacteria;Gammaproteobacteria;Pseudomonadales;Pseudomonadaceae;Pseudomonas;test;
```

I desire to obtain a new txt file with the following output for these three example lines:

```
Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Peptostreptococcales-Tissierellales;Anaerovoracaceae;[Eubacterium] nodatum group;unidentified

>Bacteria;Proteobacteria;Gammaproteobacteria;Pseudomonadales;Pseudomonadaceae;Pseudomonas;amygdali;

>Archaea;Proteobacteria;Gammaproteobacteria;Pseudomonadales;Pseudomonadaceae;Pseudomonas;test;
```

For the first example case I have used the next code taking into account the space before "Bacteria" term:

```
cat file1.txt | cut -f2- -d " " > file2.txt
```

But then the lines with the structure of the second/third line does not work well.

But I do not know how to achieve this in considering both cases.

Some condition that if Bacteria is found in each line and contains an space before it, remove all text until Bacteria term?? And if Bacteria or Archaea is found preceded with ">" symbol, then copy as is in the new text file, without any string removal.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail? `sed 's/^[^>].* Bacteria/Bacteria/' file.txt` does what you describe, but probably still generalizes poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
 awk '/>Bacteria/ || />Archaea/ { print } /^.*[ ]Bacteria/ { match($0, " Bacteria"); print substr($0,RSTART+1) }' file1.txt
```

When a line has ">Bacteria" or ">Archaea", print the line.

When the line begins with any text then a space and then "Bacteria", find where the space and then Bacteria appears in the line using awk's match function. The match function will return RSTART to specify the start position of the search text in the line. We can then use this along with awk's substr function to extract the start position plus 1 (therefore removing the space) to the end of the line.